# Cannot communicate to Google servers when using Gapps on LineageOS 16 for Moto Z Play

Tags: lineageos, motorola, gapps

I have Motorola Moto Z Play (Addison) on Android 8.0 Oreo. I installed LineageOS 16. It turns out that when I install any Gapps > ARM > Pico, Stock, etc. I can't log in to the Play Store, Gmail, Contacts, anything that involves Google. The following message appears:

> Unable to login. There was a problem communicating with Google servers. Please try again later

I tried several things to solve the problem, but nothing works:

- I tried to solve by manipulating the HOSTS file from the `/etc` folder.
- I tried downloading the new version of WebView implementation, in developer mode.
- Tried flashing LineageOS, starting the system, and then installing Gapps.

However, nothing solves it. I'm believing that it is a problem in this version of the unofficial LineageOS 16.

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: Just to make sure since [it's always recommended by the official wiki](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/addison/install), have you tried flashing Gapps *before* booting the Android system for the first time?